# Commandline flag Rescript to throw error on build for warnings

Tags: javascript, rescript

Im setting up husky which should throw error if there are any warnings during rescript build. Is there any cmd like `yarn rescript -warn-error` flag which will throw errors on warning without changing bsconfig file?

Tried with ninja options `yarn rescript -- -h` didn't find any thing for warn errors